# Google Cloud Messaging Smack Library

Tags: java, netbeans, google-cloud-messaging, smack

I am attempting to implement the Google Cloud Messaging CCS server written in Java, and  I have downloaded the Smack library from [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/). My question is, which files do I place within my project in order to use these import statement?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketInterceptor;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.PacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.PacketExtensionProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the required libraries and import them into your project
I needed

1. [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/)
2. [JsonSimple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list)
3. [XmlPull 1.1.4.c](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomspringsourceorgxmlpull114cjar.htm)
   (Click for download links)

Once you've downloaded each library you need to import them into netbeans

- Open your projects properties
- Select Libraries
- Select Add Library
- Select Create
- Add a name that indicates which library this is i.e Smack or JsonSimple so on
- Add the jar, javadoc and sources if you downloaded them for each library

Rinse and repeat till all three libraries are added to your project